# receive and use HTTP Post JSON in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a device posting temperature/GPS data to a cloud broker.  The broker then "HTTP Posts device data JSON objects to a URL of your choosing" (quoted from the broker site documentation).
How do I receive and deserialize this post in C#?  I'm using newtonsoft.json.  I've seen a similar example from stackoverflow, but for me its creating lots of errors.  My code is below.  public class Rootobject was created by pasting the JSON, so that was all automatic.  The part towards the end is what I don't know what to do with (public class testing section).  I'm not sure where it goes, and how to properly format it.
Thank you for any suggestions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace WebServiceTest1.Models
{

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public DateTime received { get; set; }
            public string authtype { get; set; }
            public string[] tags { get; set; }
            public Routingresults routingResults { get; set; }
            public string device_name { get; set; }
            public int errorcode { get; set; }
            public string source { get; set; }
            public string timestamp { get; set; }
            public string record_id { get; set; }
            public string data { get; set; }
            public int device_id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Routingresults
        {
            public int matchedRules { get; set; }
            public object[] errors { get; set; }
        }

        //This is the part I dont know where to put, or how to use properly.  
        public class Testing
        { 
           string url = "http://example.com/MethodThatReturnsJson";
           //I'm sure this needs to be the URL of the site that is POSTING.

           WebClient client = new WebClient();

           string webServiceJsonString = client.DownloadString(url);
           //This line is erroring out.  doesn't like client.DownloadString(url)

           Rootobject yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(webServiceJsonString);
           //I typed Rootobject here based on class Rootobject above, but not confident that is correct.
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So do you need an endpoint on your side that the broker will post requests to? Or do you need to issue a get request to fetch some data?

Comment: I need an endpoint.  The broker has rules, and as soon as it receives data from the monitor, it sends the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need a controller on your side that will accept post requests:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Rootobject dto)
    {
        // do something...

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This will accept post request to `api/myapi` if you have your routes setup with the default route template:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Wow, this seems perfect.  I will try as soon as I get a chance.  Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly testing localhost via fiddler.  Thanks very much.