# Parsing JSON data in C# received from HTTP POST with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, json, forms, api, urlencode

I have a C# endpoint that is receiving and parsing an HTTP Post when content type is JSON.  This works perfectly thanks to some help from stackoverflow.  I mistakenly thought this was what I needed, but have since learned the content type being posted is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Using my existing API controller, I get Nulls for all values. 
What do I need to do differently to receive the payload in this format?

Current class that works when JSON:

```
namespace WebServiceTest1.Models
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public DateTime received { get; set; }
        public string authtype { get; set; }
        public string[] tags { get; set; }
        public Routingresults routingResults { get; set; }
        public string device_name { get; set; }
        public int errorcode { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string record_id { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public int device_id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Routingresults
    {
        public int matchedRules { get; set; }
        public object[] errors { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Current Controller that works when JSON:

```
    namespace WebServiceTest1.Controllers
    {


        public class Konekt1Controller : ApiController
        {

            public IHttpActionResult Post(Rootobject dto)
            {
                //Do something here.  
                return Ok();
            }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update, here is the what is posted:

FORM/POST PARAMETERS

payload: {"received": "2016-05-13T20:43:17.845873", "authtype": "otp", "tags": ["*SOCKETAPI*", "*SIMPLESTRING*", "_DEVICE_37555_"], "device_name": "test (08921)", "errorcode": 0, "source": "1111111111111", "timestamp": "301", "data": "abc123Base64 encoded", "device_id": 37555}
key:
properties: {"url": "http://requestb.in/15jclna1", "payload_is_json": true, "user_id": 2518, "hook_payload": "*ALL*"}
userid: 2518

Comment: Credit where due.  This was my post to get this working previously testing with content type JSON.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186914/receive-and-use-http-post-json-in-c-sharp-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out.  The way the message is coming in, it is all stored in one string.  So Rather than the individual get;set; values in my original post I had to get all the values in string payload in my class object and then parse it out in the controller.

```
public string payload { get; set; }
```